# SPA when route change reset store value to default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

For example there are two components **A** and **B** in different state named **/a** and **/b**

All data is set in store data.

eg:

a.store.js

```
a:{
    data:1
}

setData(data){
  this.a.data = data;
}
```

If you change data in `A` component `a.store.js` data will be changed too.

```
handleClickA:function(){
    AStore.setData(2) // change data of store to 2
}
```

When out of **A** component and enter **B** and reenter **A** data is **2** instead of **1**;

I have tried reset value in **unmont** lifecycle it can work if set `a.data` to 1;

but If `a` is a large object I have to rewrite lots of code to reset.

If you have any good ideas, please tell me how to solve it.\

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What code do you use for resetting? It should be simple.

```
// A store
const initialState = {
  // your large object
};

A = {
  state: initialState,
  reset: function() {
    this.state = initialState;
  },
  setData: function(data) {
    // your implementation
  }
};

// Then you just
componentWillUnmount: function() {
  A.reset();
}
```